# To range date filter issue in Shopping Cart Price Rules grid in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

IF module's field type is date, then in module's grid if I filter with date, to date value's record are not shown as result in grid.

For example I have generated 3 shopping cart price rule, with date range of 2nd October to 4th October start date. [image]

If I filter with From date 2nd October and To date 4th October , How ever 4th October has result. It is not shown in grid.

[image]

This issue happens in magento 1.9 's Shopping Cart Price Rules grid. I have not add any extension for this promotion rule.

If any one has solve this issue, can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue my self, for that overwrite in local folder
`\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Filter\Date.php`

Comment line
 `$dateObj->setTimezone(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::DEFAULT_TIMEZONE);` from   `protected function _convertDate()` function.

Answer (score 0):

your magento locale settings have some error with date. If you are using en_us locale then change the date format for both short and long in this file

> lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en.xml

You will find something like this

```
<dateformatlength type="short">
    <dateformat>
        <pattern>M/d/yy</pattern>
    </dateformat>
</dateformatlength>
```

and above this for the full

```
<dateFormatLength type="full">
    <dateFormat>
        <pattern>EEEE, MMMM d, y</pattern>
    </dateFormat>
</dateFormatLength>
```

put same format for all and your problem will be resolved.
[For reference link](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-date-format/)

Comment: I have put same format for short and full but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Just refer the reference link and change the date picker format to long date format http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-date-format/.